# What is meaning of Path-like target in Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I don't have idea that what is meaning of path-like target specification.

I would like to see execute commands in Makefile that generated by cmake to know that build process of clang.
I saw it with `make -n` command, it seems like executed other `make` command like following.

```
make -f utils/hmaptool/CMakeFiles/hmaptool.dir/build.make utils/hmaptool/CMakeFiles/hmaptool.dir/build
```

I have no idea what above make command do it.

In this command, target specification is path-like.(`utils/hmaptool/CMakeFiles/hmaptool.dir/build`)
What is meaning of this?

I know non-path-like target, for example `make install` or `make clean` and so on.
But I have no idea path-like target.
What is this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above command will use the makefile `utils/hmaptool/CMakeFiles/hmaptool.dir/build.make`, and will attempt to build the target `utils/hmaptool/CMakeFiles/hmaptool.dir/build`.

You will have to check the makefile to know what exactly `build` is. Probably a PHONY target to build everything in that folder.